# Django admin inline conditional values

Tags: python, django

I am creating a inline form in the Django admin that is suppose to have conditional values.

For example, I have this models

```
class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='subcategory')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Business(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class DescriptionType (models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Descriptions (models.Model):
    descriptiontype = models.ForeignKey(DescriptionType)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
```

So, I have a `Category` ("Restaurants"), and `DescriptionType` ("Food Speciality", which belong only to "Restaurants").

So I want to create the Business "Foster Hollywood" with is category "restaurant" and I would like in the admin inline DescriptionsInline allow only to select the DescriptionTypes that belongs to the category "restaurant". My current solution displays all the values of Description Types

```
class DescriptionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Descriptions
    extra = 0

class BusinessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DescriptionsInline]
    list_display = ('name',)
    search_fields = ['name']

admin.site.register(Business, BusinessAdmin)
```

how could I make for the inline `DescriptionsInline` display only the `DescriptionTypes` from the selected category for the `Business` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution at http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/filtering-dropdown-lists-in-the-django-admin

```
class DescriptionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Descriptions
    exclude = ['modified']
    extra = 0
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, field, **kwargs):
        if field.name == 'descriptiontype':
            parent_business = self.get_object(kwargs['request'], Business)
            if parent_business == None:
                related_descriptiontype = DescriptionType.objects.all()
            else:
                related_descriptiontype = DescriptionType.objects.filter(category=parent_business.category_id)
            return forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=related_descriptiontype)
        return super(DescriptionsInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(field, **kwargs)


    def get_object(self, request, model):
        object_id = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
        try:
            object_id = int(object_id)
        except ValueError:
            return None
        return model.objects.get(pk=object_id)
```